# Smarty array show matching string

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, smarty3

Im not sure if im asking right but here is the question and it is simple:

I got an Smarty array with code

```
<td>
    {foreach from=$referrals item=referral}
        {$referral.service} - {$referral.service|@count}</br>
    {/foreach}
</td>
```

And the result is this: [Screenshot of array result](http://prntscr.com/9lf300)

My array is this:

```html
 Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (29)
  0 => Array (11)
    id => "1433"
    date => "25/12/2015"
    service => "Деловен именик"
    package => "Деловен именик"
    userid => "469"
    amount => "0.00"
    billingcycle => "One Time"
    amountdesc => "0,00 ден. One Time"
    commission => "0,00 ден."
    lastpaid => "Never"
    status => "Active"
  1 => Array (11)
    id => "1434"
    date => "25/12/2015"
    service => "Лого со податоци"
    package => "Лого со податоци"
    userid => "469"
    amount => "0.00"
    billingcycle => "One Time"
    amountdesc => "0,00 ден. One Time"
    commission => "0,00 ден."
    lastpaid => "Never"
    status => "Active"
  2 => Array (11)
    id => "1435"
    date => "25/12/2015"
    service => "Реклама во црно-бела техника на 1/6 -..."
    package => "Реклама во црно-бела техника на 1/6 -..."
    userid => "469"
    amount => "6160.00"
    billingcycle => "One Time"
    amountdesc => "6.160,00 ден. One Time"
    commission => "1.232,00 ден."
    lastpaid => "Never"
    status => "Active"
  3 => Array (11)
    id => "1436"
    date => "25/12/2015"
    service => "Лого со податоци"
    package => "Лого со податоци"
    userid => "470"
    amount => "0.00"
    billingcycle => "One Time"
    amountdesc => "1.848,00 ден. One Time"
    commission => "369,60 ден."
    lastpaid => "Never"
    status => "Active"
  4 => Array (11)
    id => "1437"
    date => "25/12/2015"
    service => "Деловен именик"
    package => "Деловен именик"
    userid => "471"
    amount => "0.00"
    billingcycle => "One Time"
    amountdesc => "0,00 ден. One Time"
    commission => "0,00 ден."
    lastpaid => "Never"
    status => "Active"
```

All i want to do is to display only array strings or value`s with name "Деловен именик" and rest from the array to hide.
So at the end to have this kind of result: [Screenshot final result -wanted](http://prntscr.com/9lf4b1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding an [`{if}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl) into your `{foreach}`-loop?

It might just be as easy as demonstraded here:

```
<td>
    {foreach from=$referrals item=referral}
        {if $referral.service eq "Деловен именик"}
            {$referral.service} - {$referral.service|@count}</br>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</td>
```

However, this is a rather specialized approach, you'd have to edit the template if you want to filter something different. If this is the base for a more general solution, you'd be better off coding something in php, possibly another item in your array to filter.

Comment: I tried that a couple of times but i dont get any result... not even an error.
Also i just edited my question, i add the array list (using {debug}) in my template file...

Comment: Which encoding are you using in both cases? Please make sure the encoding of your smarty template file and the encoding within your php scripts are the same, otherwise the `eq` will not trigger.

Comment: Yea... damn i totally forgot that i dont edit the template file in notepad++ , instead i edited in CuteFTP :( so the UTF-8 encoding doesnt work (cant save the file as UTF-8)
So now its okey > http://prntscr.com/9lmger

Comment: Btw @Bjoern can i make sum-total for that array? Like to get:
Service: "Деловен именик" - Total: 9 items

Comment: @ViktorG Yes that can be done, though I'd advise summing it in your php code, since this is where the logic should usually be placed.

Comment: I guess i should try something like `{assign var="sum" value="`$sum+$referral.service`"}` + {assign var="sum" value=0} but im not sure tho :)

Comment: @ViktorG Aye, this is one way to accomplish this. But again, I'd advise doing the math in the php code. This is where the application logic should usually be placed.